# replace proxyless master to haproxy as advertise-address

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-on-premises

I've got an on premise k8s cluster (1.26) running with a single master.
Now I've added an external haproxy load balancer which points its backend to that master node.

```
frontend kubernetes
        bind *:6443

backend kubernetes-master-nodes-tooling
        mode tcp

        server k8s-master-1 10.03.2.170:6443 check fall 3 rise 2
```

now kubectl can reach the cluster at least.

```
$ kubectl get po
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.6.0.1, 10.23.32.90, not 10.23.2.175

$ kubectl get po --insecure-skip-tls-verify 
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

But of course unauthorized is emitted as the master was initialized with

`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`

and it needs api-advertise-address

```
kubeadm init \
  --cri-socket unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock \
  --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 \
  --apiserver-advertise-address <haproxyIP>
```

But there is a production rabbitmq "StatefulSet" running on the cluster and I want the downtime to be as short as possible.

Can I just do a new kubeadm reset and init and then reset and rejoin the worker nodes?
Or must all rabbitmq (and others like grafana) configs be reapplied then also?